# What tools would I need to make a wood accent wall?

Tags: walls, tools, woodworking

Just moved into my first house (yikes!) and the wife and I would like to turn a wall in our living room into a wood accent wall. The plan is to use Tongue and groove Carsiding, stained to our liking, affixed to the wall. What I need to know is:

1. Is this the best material for the job?
2. What tools will I need?

I current own: A dremel, a jig saw, a power drill, a 150psi compressor, and an orbital sander. I did a little research and I think that for attaching the siding to the studs in the wall, I will use a compressor driven brad nailer. For making cuts I will use a mitre saw. Is this a good idea?

Comment: I edited the question to focus more on the home improvement, and less on shopping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are fixing this to a wall with drywall on it, you will need 2 1/2" long finish nails to toenail it with, at the tongue edge. If you are staining it, DO NOT face nail it. If you are painting it, well nail it anywhere you please. The wood you are planning to use will work very well, make sure it will give you the look you want by making a sample, say 3' square and place it so it will take on the light that come from windows, lights, what have you. This is done at the wall you are planning to cover. The surrounding colors of the painted wall or stained cabinets that are nearby will play into the choice too.

The saw you linked to is a good saw, maybe more than what you need to do the job, It is made for heavier material but it will still cut small trim pieces too. I have used another brand that was made like this and it cut very small pieces too. It will serve you well for many years to come if you get it. Be mindful of its cut capacity, it looks like it has a capacity if 5 3/4" at the 90 degree setting, it will be much shorter on the 45 degree setting. If you are making all square cuts, no problem. I would consider getting an 8" slide compound saw, larger capacity, lightweight. I have an old Hitachi 8" compound slide, I have owned for the past 15 years, worked it to death, replaced the armature once, the brushes twice, did it myself, still doing a great job. Here is a [link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001FOQU3G) to the modern replacement of what I have been using

Comment: What do you mean by "do not face nail it." My plan was to nail it into the stud from the tongue, the portion that is hidden by the next board placed. Is this a good idea?

Comment: Yes, that's what he means by "do not face nail it".  Though you'll likely have to do some of that at each end.  May be able to cover it with a trim strip.  Are you running the boards horizontal or vertical? You also won't be able to hit a stud for most of the boards if you hang it vertical, though you can hit the plates top & bottom.  Consider liquid nails construction adhesive, but know you'll be replacing drywall if you ever change your mind.

Comment: @CoAstroGeek The boards will run horizontal, parallel with the floor. Should be able to run sections in between studs. I would like to vary the length of the board to make it look varied, however. So, maybe liquid nails will be of use to me for some of the boards.

Comment: If you're running them horizontally there won't be any problem hitting studs.  And it's tongue and groove, so even when you don't end on a stud, it should still be fine - I would just nail it.

Answer (score 1):

For tools:

I own a Porter Cable FN250B 16 gauge brad nailer and it's great for this type of application.  It costs more but you will also get a range from 3/4 to 2 1/2 inches.  It is on Amazon for a $140 ($92 used).

I'd recommend selecting the material before buying the miter saw. A ten inch saw is only going to handle up to six inch material, so if you buy wider material, you'll have regrets.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need some way to rip material to width.  Cheapest would be a hand-held circular saw, and a long straight-edge & clamps (or steady hand).  Better option would be a table or radial arm saw.

Comment: In what way would you keep the would propped up to use a circular saw? Two saw horses?

Comment: Sure - I've also seen people use a piece of foam insulation board on the floor, but that's typically for cutting sheet goods where you might have trouble reaching the middle.